# Rendering TileLayer inside a polygon

Tags: openlayers

I need to Render the a tile layer only for a country which is a polygon. I tried to get the extent of the polygon and limit the rendering to that extent but its not what i need as the shape of the extent is always a rectangle.
So my question actually is, how can I render a tile layer inside a polygon.

Comment: duplicate of [Render Tile layer only insde a polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60500095/render-tile-layer-only-insde-a-polygon)

Answer (score 2):

You can use ol-ext ol/filter/Crop to crop a layer inside a feature area.
See example: https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/filter/map.filter.crop.html